# Firebase Problems

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning android studio, and at a section through the guide I follows, the firebase console has changed design dramatically and I'm stuck in the tutorials.

The step is where I'm supposed to connect my app with firebase and load(save) data into the firebase, but I can't get it to cooperate with my code.

I quite don't get it how I'm going to create the database, I've tried with the following:

1. Add colleciton -> Collection ID: **Users** -> Field: **Users** -> Value: **True**

*but when i run the app, nothing shows up in firebase?*

This is the code I put in my app:

**LOGIN CLASS**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*


class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mAuth:FirebaseAuth?=null

    private var database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private var myRef=database.reference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    }

    fun buLoginEvent(view:View){

        LoginToFirebase(etEmail.text.toString(),etPassword.text.toString())
    }

    fun LoginToFirebase(email:String,password:String){
        mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this){task ->

                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Successful login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    val currentUser=mAuth!!.currentUser
                    // Save in database
                    if(currentUser!=null) {

                        myRef.child("Users").child(SplitString(currentUser.email.toString())).setValue(currentUser.uid)
                    }

                    LoadMain()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        LoadMain()
    }

    fun LoadMain(){
        val currentUser=mAuth!!.currentUser

        if(currentUser!=null) {

            var intent=Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("email", currentUser.email)
            intent.putExtra("uid", currentUser.uid)

            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    fun SplitString(str:String):String{
        var splitStr=str.split("@")
        return splitStr[0]
    }
}
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
// Database instance
    private var database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private var myRef=database.reference

    var myEmail:String?=null

    private var mFireBaseAnalytics:FirebaseAnalytics?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mFireBaseAnalytics= FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)

        val b:Bundle=intent.extras
        myEmail=b.getString("email")
    }
```

Comment: Can you login successful ? If your login succeed, there should be some users appears in the `Authentication` tab of Firebase console.

Comment: Yes, login Authentication works perfectly, shows email and uid. But in the database collection nothing appears..

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to check `Authentication` tab in Firebase, if any users noted then it means your code is working if not noted then it means there is a problem in your code. check the image below for clarity on `Authentication`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR5cR.png)

Comment: Yes Authentication works perfect, but I wanna have it saved in database for users in order to make multiplayer available, sending requests and accepting game requests.. 

How do I upload a image, so I can show you what design I mean, I'm having difficulties to explain I believe.

Comment: Have you checked the database rules? if not once go through them https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart?authuser=0#configuring_rules

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

That's how it look, should I edit this?

Comment: I think you are using Firebase-realtimeDatabase, note FireStore? This is mine `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`

Comment: Try this which allow the users to write data `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @Wesely Error saving rules – Line 4: Unexpected '"rules"'.; Line 3: Missing 'match' keyword before path.; Line 4: mismatched input '"rules"' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}; Line 6: Unexpected '}'.

RameshNaidu That caused my app to immediately crash on startup

Comment: Using cloud Firestore is somewhat difficult for Beginners. So I suggest using Real-time database for saving user data and to retrieve the user data. If you still want to use Cloud Firestore then go through official firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/   and to understand firebase do some more research on it.

Comment: Okey, So I tried with real-time database but it don't show the saved data as node?

Answer (score 0):

You should create first of all a child User with a ID, usually a *token*. Inside that u'll create another child with the name of *images* or something else.
In theory, this method will make your life easier to find the information ;D

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, I understand that the authentication works perfectly and you are trying to add some data to the database. As I see in your code, you are trying to add data to the Firebase realtime database and not to Cloud Firestore. As I see in your code, you are using methods that are apart of Firebase realtime database SDK and not from Cloud Firestore, which is a total different product. If you are adding data to Firebase realtime database, you should select the `Raltime Database` **tab** as in the following image:

[image]